# Shadow only showing on playback

Tags: rendering, shadows

Any idea way i am getting a different shadow on playback ?.
When i click the play head, scrub or play. i get a shadow,
on stop and render i get a totally different result

[image: Playhead not clicked]

[image: Playhead clicked]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you please share your .blend file so we could better dissect the problem? Upload it to https://blend-exchange.com or something similar, please.

Comment: Hello and welcome, Ziv.  Instead of posting an answer with additional info, please [edit] your original post.  L0Lock took care of this one for you, just info for the future and I didn't want you to feel bad when your answer on this page is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how shadows are calculated in Eevee when "Soft Shadows" is enabled:

[image: soft shadows]

When this is enabled, it first calculates hard shadows and soften them afterwards. But when in playback or moving our viewport around, it doesn't have the time to soften the shadow before a new frame is display, hence you see the hard shadow instead.

It's not a big deal on itself, the final render will be fine, it's just the render preview that is a bit biased for performance’s sake.
In fact, this isn't the only effect that can be significantly impacted during viewport playback or movement, it can also impact the ambient occlusion, volumetric shaders, bloom, reflections, ... Pretty much everything.